# For Loop using Google Scripts to read an email

Tags: google-apps-script

We are trying to create a script that reads through certain emails based on how they are labeled and write certain content to a spreadsheet. We are able to write only one email worth of data to the spreadsheet before our loop states `.getPlainBody()` is undefined. Below is our code and the exact error we are getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPlainBody' of undefined
myFunction  @ Code.gs:12
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("105dNWvYNTPzqw1YHHclu00vKLclyEi9UjQBoX0_JTYM");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Daily Log Data");
    
  var label =GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Test");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  Logger.log(threads);

  for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var mess = threads[i].getMessages();
    var pmsg = mess[i].getPlainBody();

    Logger.log(mess);
  
    // Mutual Aid
    if (pmsg.includes("MutualAid: ")>0) {
      var endMut = pmsg.substring(mess.indexOf("MutualAid: ")+11,pmsg.length);
      var Mut = endMut.substring(0,endMut.indexOf("\n"));
      sheet.appendRow([Mut]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("105dNWvYNTPzqw1YHHclu00vKLclyEi9UjQBoX0_JTYM");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Daily Log Data");
  var lbl = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Test");
  var threads = lbl.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var mess = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < mess.length; j++) {
      var pmsg = mess[j].getPlainBody();
      if (pmsg.includes("MutualAid: ") > 0) {
        var endMut = pmsg.substring(mess.indexOf("MutualAid: ") + 11, pmsg.length);
        var Mut = endMut.substring(0, endMut.indexOf("\n"));
        sh.appendRow([Mut]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the reformatting too. I am just getting into this so any help is great.